# Orientation of WebView - Monotouch

Tags: webview, xamarin.ios, orientation

I have a UIWebView that I can't seem to get to rotate. Everything in my app appears to work properly so far except for orientation (I want all orientations supported).

In my code below, I'm using a WebViewDelegate in order to present users with a choice of which local application they would like to open the files downloaded from the website with vs. just handing it off to Safari).

In my UIViewController this is set (properly from what I can tell)

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
{
    return true;        
}
```

Here is my AppDelegate.

```
Register ("AppDelegate")] public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate { // class-level declarations UIWindow window; UIWebView webView;

public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    // create a new window instance based on the screen size
    window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame);


    webView = new UIWebView (window.Bounds);
    window.AddSubview (webView); 

    string url = "https://www.myURL.com";
    webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (url)));
    webView.WeakDelegate = new WebViewDelegate();
    webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;

    var keys = new object[] { "UserAgent" };
    var objects = new object[] { "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3" };
    var dictionnary = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(objects, keys);

    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.RegisterDefaults(dictionnary);

    // make the window visible
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

    return true;
}



}
public class WebViewDelegate: UIWebViewDelegate{

UIDocumentInteractionController docControl;

public WebViewDelegate () : base()
{ 

}


public override bool ShouldStartLoad (UIWebView webView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
{

    var docString = request.Url.ToString ();
    Uri uri = new Uri (docString);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension (uri.ToString ()).ToLower();
    var canShow = false;

    switch (ext) {
    case ".xls":
    case ".xlxs":
    case ".doc":
    case ".docx":
    case ".pdf":
    case ".jpeg":
    case ".jpg":
    case ".gif":
    case ".png":
    case ".mov":
    case ".mp4":
    case ".ogv":
    case ".webm":
    case ".avi":
    case ".mpeg":
    case ".mp3":
    case ".wmv":
        canShow = true;
        break;
    }


    if (canShow) {

        WebClient _webClient = new WebClient();
        _webClient.Headers.Add("SecretKey","SecretKey");

        string filename = Path.GetFileName(uri.ToString());

        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string filePath = Path.Combine(path, filename);

        _webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri,filePath);
        _webClient.DownloadFileCompleted +=  (sender, e) => {


            var docData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, docData);

            InvokeOnMainThread(delegate {
                docControl = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath));
                docControl.Delegate = new UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate();
                docControl.PresentOptionsMenu(new Rectangle(0,-260,320,320),webView,true);
            });
        };

        //open it in safari...
        //UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(request.Url);


        return false;
    }

    return true;

    }

}
```

And of course, in my Info.plist file I do have all (both portraits and both landscapes) supported for iPhone and iPad.

Any help anyone can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your UIWebView is not the View of a UIViewController but attached to the UIWindow directly. I suggest reading into UIViewController/MVCV basics first.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution at [here](http://www.tipsabc.com/2015/xamarin-forms-how-to-resize-the-webview-after-rotation-in-ios/) by using the custom renderer, but does not work in iOS 7.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace iOS {
public class MyWebViewRenderer: WebViewRenderer {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e) {

        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        this.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleDimensions;
        this.AutosizesSubviews = true;
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews() {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        var screenBound = UIKit.UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        var offSetH = GetStatusBarHeight();

        NativeView.Bounds = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(
            screenBound.X,
            screenBound.Y + offSetH,
            screenBound.Width,
            screenBound.Height - offSetH);
    }
}
}
```